# How to have different icon for active and inactive state of tabbar in flutter and also maintain indicator animation

Tags: flutter

I have five tabs looking like below

```
Tab(
    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
      _getSvgName(
        tabIndex: 0,
      ),
    ),
    child: Text(
      '홈',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 12.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

The code that decides the name of the svg icon is below

```
String _getSvgName({
    @required int tabIndex,
  }) {
    String root;

    if (tabIndex == 0) {
      root = 'assets/svgs/tab-home';
    } else if (tabIndex == 1) {
      root = 'assets/svgs/tab-posts';
    } else if (tabIndex == 2) {
      root = 'assets/svgs/tab-news';
    } else if (tabIndex == 3) {
      root = 'assets/svgs/tab-alarm';
    } else if (tabIndex == 4) {
      root = 'assets/svgs/tab-profile';
    } else {
      throw Exception('index out of bounds');
    }

    if (tabIndex == _tabController.index) {
//      root = root + '.svg';

      root = root + '-active.svg';
    } else {
      root = root + '.svg';
    }

    return root;
  }
```

I am also listening to changes of tabController so that I can update the current index of the tabbar. The problem is that once I run `setState()` to reflect the tab index change, the indicator's sliding animation is killed - it shift immediately to the next tab instead of smoothly sliding over like the default behaviour. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @anoop4real no unfortunately I never got to solve this problem